# accessing cron script in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, cron

I am using Zend framework. I want to create an easy script for sending me an email with statistics every day. That is the easy part.

The cron script execution with my provider can be only set up by an URL link.

How can I make sure this URL can be only accessed by the machine, and not by any user or robot that tries the URL by accident or something.

I want to avoid executing the cron script by anyone else than the machine that is supposed to access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the cron script retrieve:

```
http://yourdomain.com/path/to/script.php?token=743cc5a35d28aa7d22d4e93
```

and then in the script:

```
if( ! ( isset($_GET['token']) && $_GET['token'] === '743cc5a35d28aa7d22d4e93' ) ) {
    exit;
}
```

It doesn't guarantee that the request is genuine, but it will prevent accidental invocation of your script.

Answer (score 1):

If the provider is coming from a static IP, it should be as simple as checking `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` against a predefined IP.